# What happens when a compass is suspended inside a current carrying solenoid?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Suppose I have a current carrying solenoid with a strong magnetic field inside and outside it.
Now I bring a good compass inside that solenoid now I would like you to tell me the direction of **North Pole** of that compass in which it will get deflected, either  towards the South Pole or North Pole of the solenoid.
Please Explain your answer.

For more details please view this:-
[Where is the deflection of compass needle when placed inside a current carrying solenoid?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/355944/166967)

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what your question is.

Comment: You have to tell me the direction of deflection of North Pole of a compass when it is placed inside a current carrying solenoid

Comment: Will it be deflected towards North Pole of that solenoid or towards South Pole

Comment: "Explain with reason" sounds a lot like a homework question... also "you have to tell me" is not really the tone I think you are looking for. "I would like you to tell me", maybe?

Comment: Arpit, what steps have you taken to solve this problem?

Comment: Please see this question for further details.         https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/355944/166967

Comment: Hey CR Drost see the question above to know your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compass will line up so that it's field lines align with the field lines of the solenoid. This will mean the north pole of the compass will point towards the north pole of the solenoid.

Comment: See this  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/355944/166967

Answer (score 0):

If the Earth were a giant magnet, what we call the magnetic north pole would be that magnet's south pole. (At the Earth's north pole magnetic field lines enter the Earth.)

The north (seeking) pole of the compass magnet which points normally to the north pole of the Earth (the Earth's magnetic south pole) will point to the south pole of the solenoid.

Comment: You have this backwards. The needle's red half is the north pole of a magnet; Earth's North Pole is the south pole of its magnetic field.

Comment: Really? Oh yes, I see you are correct. 
Interesting. Thanks.
I'll back edit that in.